# Google translation api call

Tags: python, api, translation, text-analytics-api, google-translation-api

I am using the Google translation api paid version to translate comments in python.

I am calling the rest api link in my Python code

I would like to known if I pass 1000 comments at a time (strings) how many times api is called and also would like to know what is the meaning of one api call.

Comment: 1000 comments as 1 input text = 1 API call.

Answer (score 0):

As the user @doniyor said in the comment, "1000 comments as 1 input text = 1 API call".

Check [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-api-call) see answers for "What is an API call?". Quote:

> "Every time you make a call to a server in name of an application using a SDKs or a API, it counts as an API request or API call."